# Is there an SVG Map library like Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, maps, google-visualization

I'm looking for large-scale world maps that I can shade by country. Google Charts has an API for this but it only allows you to generate a small map (440x220 px). Does anyone know of a way to generate such maps with an open-source library?

Comment: Do you need to accommodate IE? I ask because there's not SVG support in IE, just VML...

Comment: There's svgweb that enables IE to show SVG (using a flash-based shim), http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/. An example of a dynamic SVG map using svgweb, see here: http://vis.uell.net/gsvg/electionAtlasGermany.html

Answer (score 6):

I work on a library which provides functionality similar to described in the question. It's called jVectorMap. This is a jQuery plugin, which allows to place world map components on web pages using SVG in modern browsers and VML in IE 6-8. You can customize it in many ways, changing look and behavior of map. Unfortunately documentation is not ready yet. You can check out example and code here http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/.

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, google released [Geochart Maps](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart), an update to the geomap. It creates SVG maps, and you can make them whatever size you want, with aspect ratio or not. 
I developed a plugin to build maps using this API for wordpress. 
Check it out at http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/

Answer (score 2):

With the Wikipedia [SVG Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Blank_maps) you can "shade" countries by simply using CSS.

Some examples of using such maps (SVG, CSS, HTML, JS) can be found [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/mapcolorizer/). That will export either a full map, or just the stylesheet which can be applied to a local copy of the map. I'd recommend using [Opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/next) for the best viewing experience, but it should work in all the browsers that support SVG.

Answer (score 2):

These days, I would recommend using either [Polymaps](http://polymaps.org/) or [d3](http://www.d3js.org). The former is a full-fledged "slippy maps" library that works with SVG. The latter is a visualization library that works with SVG and has a growing amount of geo features. If you don't need pan, zoom, and other "slippy" features, then try d3, like this example: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/choropleth.html

Answer (score 1):

The [Geomap](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html), from the Google Visualization API, can be sized as large as you want; however, it uses Flash instead of SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a lot of [SVG Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Blank_maps), but it is not a library.

Answer (score 0):

As its author, I recommend http://www.makeclickablemap.com for SVG based mapping.
It has growing number of countries and a beautiful easy to use interface to edit your maps that you can embed anywhere using an iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Check amMap: http://www.ammap.com - we have SVG maps of most countries of the world and a API for making these maps interactive, zoomable, etc.

Disclaimer - I am the author of the amMap.